# How do I delete elements of a list of strings, if they don't have a specific letter at a specific index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program, where there is a list of words (large in my program, but this is a test example with a small list) and the user inputs a word (this is a simplified example, where I've hard-coded the input word, "angus") and a list of indices of the input word, which indicate which letters the input word should share with the list, deleting words from my list that don't meet these requirements.

In my example, for simplicity I've used the index 0, meaning that I want my test list to be reduced to words that start with the first letter of the input word, in this case "a". Note that in future iterations, there may be multiple indices required, i.e. words that start with "an" or start with "a" and have a "g" in the middle, etc.

I'm finding that the words in the list that do fulfil the requirements are tested, but my list iteration then tests every other word, hence deleting only half of the incompatible words. Why?

When I change the index to, say 4 (wanting words that end in "s", which happen to just be the last 3 words), it tests every other word in the list, until it gets to the ones I want and test all of these in turn. Can anyone spot the problem?

I've added prints at every stage so I could better see what's going on, but it's even more puzzling.

```
green_positions_python_list = [0] #list of indeces I want my list and word input to have in common
test_fullwordlist = ['abbey','asken','antar','barke','crent','cnelk','hugus','loges','smars']
word_input = 'angus'
word_input_list = list(word_input)

for i in range(0,len(green_positions_python_list)):
    for word in test_fullwordlist:
        print(f"current word: {word}")
        word_test = list(word)
        print(f"word test: {word_test}")
        position_index = green_positions_python_list[i]
        if word_test[position_index] != word_input_list[position_index]:
            print(f"word to remove: {word}")
            test_fullwordlist.remove(word)


print(f"test fullword list: {test_fullwordlist}")
```

Output:

```
current word: abbey
word test: ['a', 'b', 'b', 'e', 'y']
current word: asken
word test: ['a', 's', 'k', 'e', 'n']
current word: antar
word test: ['a', 'n', 't', 'a', 'r']
current word: barke
word test: ['b', 'a', 'r', 'k', 'e']
word to remove: barke
current word: cnelk
word test: ['c', 'n', 'e', 'l', 'k']
word to remove: cnelk
current word: loges
word test: ['l', 'o', 'g', 'e', 's']
word to remove: loges

test fullword list: ['abbey', 'asken', 'antar', 'crent', 'hugus', 'smars']
```

As you see, it tests all the "a" words, then every other remaining word, meaning some that ought to be removed, remain in the list.

Output I want:

```
test fullword list: ['abbey', 'asken', 'antar']
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Removing elements from a list while you iterate over it has pitfalls. It'd be more straightforward to construct a new list and just add the elements you want to "keep" to it. You can then reassign the new list to the original variable name if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

```
green_positions_python_list = [0] #list of indeces I want my list and word input to have in common
test_fullwordlist = ['abbey','asken','antar','barke','crent','cnelk','hugus','loges','smars']
word_input = 'angus'
word_input_list = list(word_input)

def is_shared(w1: str, w2: str, indexes: list):
    for index in indexes:
        if (index >= len(w1)) or (index >= len(w2)) or (w1[index] != w2[index]):
            return False
    return True

res = []

for word in test_fullwordlist:
    if is_shared(word, word_input, green_positions_python_list):
        res.append(word)

# OR
# res = [
#     word
#     for word in test_fullwordlist
#     if is_shared(word, word_input, green_positions_python_list)
# ]

print(f"test fullword list: {res}")
```